# PHP export array to json for an angular app

Tags: php, angularjs, json, controller

I exported data from MySql db to Json object. 
What I want to achieve is actually to see the front end data manipulations by angular. 
I think that the problem is in my controller. I placed the Json object inline in `ng-init`and it works great.

I tried to lean on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064570/get-json-data-from-a-php-file-for-an-angular-scope) but with not much success

This is my HTML file

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="direction: ltr">
    </div>
    <h1>תוצאות שאלון</h1>
    <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
        <!--ng-controller="ContentCtrl"-->
        <table class="table" id="results">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>q 1</th>
                    <th>q 2</th>
                    <th>q 3</th>
                    <th>textarea</th>
                    <th>phone</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="answer in answers">
                    <td>{{answer.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.q1}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.q2}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.q3}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.textarea}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the controller.js file

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json.php')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.answers = data;
    });
}]);
```

This is my the json i get at the `json.php` file, `controller.js` and `json.php` are in the same folder

```
[{"id":"6","time":"1453381291","answers":"x","q1":"2","q2":"3","q3":"1","textarea":"test","phone":"954472","name":"Jane"},{"id":"5","time":"1453364067","answers":"x","q1":"1","q2":"2","q3":"3","textarea":"test 1","phone":"954472","name":"John"},{"id":"4","time":"1453363983","answers":"x","q1":"4","q2":"3","q3":"2","textarea":"test 2","phone":"954472","name":"David"}]
```

Now, I do not get any related error at the consule but I do not see data either.

any help would be great.

Comment: If you do a `console.log` in the `success` does it log anything ?

Comment: I added console lod insile se success scope like this:  '    .success(function(data) {

        $scope.answers = data;

        console.log('test');
    });'     and i see the 'test ' string in the consoule

Comment: Allright, could you make a plunkr with the code ?

Comment: Can you try  `<tr ng-repeat="answer in answers.data">`? Because, the results would most like be within the `data` property.

Comment: added .data but i dont get any errors, i should see the errors at the consule, right?

Comment: @MartijnWelker I had a little troubles with plunker, so i uploaded the files here.  http://goo.gl/gTmV77   this is the pafe where i should see the data

Comment: The answer to this question can be find here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949130/getting-json-with-angularjs-from-php-is-not-showing-on-controller

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the javascript files you have included as below this will resolve your problem.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

For `jquery.js` file must load before the boostrap.min.js.

Comment: I changed the order as you suggested but still cant see the data

Comment: I had not made any chages in your logic it works at my end by just changing the order of the files. Try to write the code from controller.js in html page only instead of writing it in separate file. Or try by changing the code as below: `$http.get('./json.php')`

Comment: can you please check my link again? i changed the files as you suggested. is there still something missing?  goo.gl/gTmV77

Comment: You have some error in js.js at line 54:Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined kindly resolve this issue first.

Comment: Thank you. i fixed the error in line 54. also added the script to the result.php file. instead of linking it but i still dont see the data. may the problem be at the module or the controller? i tried to add the Json inline and it works...

Comment: I think on your server you don't have sufficient permission to read the file because in console it is showing me error as `GET http://dev-livnes.com/surveyii/js/json.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: o.k. i moved the files and data base to another server. now i dont get the error but i still dont see the data. here is the link seveloff.com/survey/results.php     the json file can be seen here seveloff.com/survey/json.php