# Getting JSON with AngularJS from PHP is not showing on controller

Tags: php, angularjs, json, controller

I am trying to build an AngularJS based front-end to a PHP back-end base application. I build the JSON object with a PHP & MySQL query. The JSON is exported correctly and the data is shown if i use the objet inline with an `ng-init` directive. But when I mount the `Json.php` file on the controller something seem to be wrong because I don't see any data.

[This is](http://seveloff.com/survey/results.php) the link to the example, Here the controller is beneath the `</body>`tag.

This is the main page

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="direction: ltr">

        </div>
        <h1>תוצאות שאלון</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="ContentCtrl">          

        <table class="table" id="results" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>q1</th>
                    <th>q2</th>
                    <th>q3</th>
                    <th>textarea</th>
                    <th>phone</th>
                    <th>name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="answer in answers.data">

                    <td>{{answer.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.q1}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.q2}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.q3}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.textarea}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{answer.name}}</td>
</tr>



                <?php/* 
                $table = new Results();
                $table->allrows();
                 */?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/js.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
```

this is the controller:

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ContentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json.php')

    .success(function(data) {

        $scope.answers = data;

        console.log('test');
    });
}]);
```

Maybe the module should be on another page? 
I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941448/php-export-array-to-json-for-an-angular-app/34941966?noredirect=1#comment57616213_34941966) earlier. Maybe it can help somehow.

Comment: On your linked example page the `json.php` is giving a 500.

Comment: sorry, i chaged the server, this the new link http://seveloff.com/survey/json.php and this is the new link to the page   http://seveloff.com/survey/results.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON that your `json.php` file responds with is just an array of objects.  But your `ng-repeat` is iterating over `answers.data`, which is undefined.  You should iterate over `answers` since that's the array.

```
<tr ng-repeat="answer in answers">
```

If for some reason you don't want to change the `ng-repeat`, then you can change your controller so that it wraps `data` in an object like this:

```
$scope.answers = { data: data };
```

Comment: thank you. so what you suggest me to do? how can I bind the JSON in `json.php` to the `answers.data` in the controller

Comment: Why not just change your `ng-repeat` like I showed?

Comment: The ng-repeat at the file is exactley as you wrote. I dont see the difference between what is the file and the directuve that you suggested. What am i missing here?

Comment: you were right, the `.data` was what made the data not to be shown