# Calling PHP with AngularJS/AJAX/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ajax

I am very new to PHP and AJAX so please advise if this method is actually even appropriate.

Basically what I am looking to do is populate a .JSON with data from a Microsoft SQL Server. I am using a PHP file to set up the connection which will also populate the .JSON file which can then be read from to populate a ionic list. I am able to read from a .JSON no problem but the issue comes when I call the PHP file.

I am not sure what the best method is for calling it. I've tried AJAX, AngularJS and JavaScript methods but it seems that when it comes to accessing the PHP file they fail but without exception.

This is the code that was able to trigger the .success

```
angular.module('someApp').controller('someCrtl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("app/dataLink.php").success(

    function phpCall(data) {        
    $scope.info= data;            
}
)});
```

Note that $scope.info = data; is not what i want to do. What this controller should do is call the php which will populate the .JSON then read from that same .JSON to populate $scope.info

What i can see is that it never actually $http.get the PHP document (I put a breakpoint within it and it was never triggered) but it still continues into .success without exceptions.

I hope that this is enough to go on.

Any other relevant info might be:

- Using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
- Using AngularJS with Ionic
- Using PHP Tools for Visual Studio by Devsense

Any advice would be much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: "What this controller should do is call the php which will populate the .JSON then read from that same .JSON to populate $scope.info" - it looks like that is exactly what the code _is_ doing. What is happening now to make you think it is not? are there any error messages in your console dev tools (F12)? And if you go to the PHP URL directly in the browser, does it appear to return the correct data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET json data from a php file for an Angular scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064570/get-json-data-from-a-php-file-for-an-angular-scope)

Comment: What is should do is when I load up the list and run this controller it should go to the PHP connection file which will populate the JSON from the server then read from the JSON to populate the list. This is not happening as the PHP file is never accessed therefore the JSON isnt populated and it seems to return null which avoids an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('someApp').controller('someCrtl', function ($scope, $http) {


    function success(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $scope.info = result;
    };

    function error(result) {
        alert("error");
    };

    $http.get("app/dataLink.php").then(success, error);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From AngularJs doc:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated.

[AngularJS: API: $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Replace your success block with something like:

```
.then(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
}
```

See if you get any response when you inspect. Also watch your "network" tab if you use chrome, it will show if the call was successful (200) or something went wrong (500) and debug the problem that way.