# Bootstrap Angular Calendar Events From MySQL Database

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I recently added the angular bootstrap calendar to my website. I have figured out how to populate the calendar manually.

I was hoping that someone could either point me in the right direction on how to populate this calendar from a database (A good source to read). Or to share some code to get me started.

I have to be completely honest that I have no idea where to start with populating the *.js file that is responsible for displaying the events. Manually, yes I know how to, but don't know what to do from a database side.

Any help will really be appreciated.

```
angular.module('mwl.calendar.docs', ['mwl.calendar', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'colorpicker.module']);
angular
  .module('mwl.calendar.docs') //you will need to declare your module with the dependencies ['mwl.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']
  .controller('KitchenSinkCtrl', function(moment, alert, calendarConfig) {

    var vm = this;

    //These variables MUST be set as a minimum for the calendar to work
    vm.calendarView = 'month';
    vm.viewDate = new Date();
    var actions = [{
      label: '<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>',
      onClick: function(args) {
        alert.show('Edited', args.calendarEvent);
      }
    }, {
      label: '<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>',
      onClick: function(args) {
        alert.show('Deleted', args.calendarEvent);
      }
    }];
    vm.events = [
      {
        title: 'An event',
        color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.warning,
        startsAt: moment().startOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').add(8, 'hours').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'week').add(9, 'hours').toDate(),
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        actions: actions
      }, {
        title: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> <span class="text-primary">Leon event</span>, with a <i>html</i> title',
        color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.info,
        startsAt: moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().add(5, 'days').toDate(),
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        actions: actions
      }, {
        title: 'My customized event',
        color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.important,
        startsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(7, 'hours').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(19, 'hours').toDate(),
        recursOn: 'year',
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,
        actions: actions
      }
    ];

    vm.cellIsOpen = true;

    vm.addEvent = function() {
      vm.events.push({
        title: 'New event',
        startsAt: moment().startOf('day').toDate(),
        endsAt: moment().endOf('day').toDate(),
        color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.important,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true
      });
    };

    vm.eventClicked = function(event) {
      alert.show('Clicked', event);
    };

    vm.eventEdited = function(event) {
      alert.show('Edited', event);
    };

    vm.eventDeleted = function(event) {
      alert.show('Deleted', event);
    };

    vm.eventTimesChanged = function(event) {
      alert.show('Dropped or resized', event);
    };

    vm.toggle = function($event, field, event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
      $event.stopPropagation();
      event[field] = !event[field];
    };

    vm.timespanClicked = function(date, cell) {

      if (vm.calendarView === 'month') {
        if ((vm.cellIsOpen && moment(date).startOf('day').isSame(moment(vm.viewDate).startOf('day'))) || cell.events.length === 0 || !cell.inMonth) {
          vm.cellIsOpen = false;
        } else {
          vm.cellIsOpen = true;
          vm.viewDate = date;
        }
      } else if (vm.calendarView === 'year') {
        if ((vm.cellIsOpen && moment(date).startOf('month').isSame(moment(vm.viewDate).startOf('month'))) || cell.events.length === 0) {
          vm.cellIsOpen = false;
        } else {
          vm.cellIsOpen = true;
          vm.viewDate = date;
        }
      }

    };

  });
```

vm.events is the section I think that needs to be populated by the DB.

Comment: there not much to it, have your server return a timestamp to your angular service, create a new Date object with it and supply it to the directive

Comment: Currently the calendar is populating from the example.js file that comes in the github project. Would you populate this file with a SQL Script? Do you use JSON to return the info in the correct format?

Comment: what's your backend? how do you fetch data from the database and provide it to the client ?

Comment: I'm using a MySQL database. I normally collect all info from the BD using PHP SQL scripts. But for the calendar it's in a js file. Will add the "Example.js" file code to my question.

Comment: you database is mySql, use something like phpMyAdmin, create a table, have one of the columns return a timestamp, use a php script to call the table, map the records you're getting into php objects and provide them to angular.

Comment: Building the DB table to hold the calendar events I'm okay with. I just don't know how to pass these onto angular.

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25064570/get-json-data-from-a-php-file-for-an-angular-scope

Comment: Thanks, will look at that. It almost looks like what I need.